# What is the length property of the Function, Array, and Object constructors?

Tags: javascript, oop, semantics

What is length static property of Function,Array and Object constructor?

Static methods makes sense but what about length static property?

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array)
["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype", "isArray"]

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Function)
["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype"]
```

**Note: I am getting answers about length property of Function.prototype that is not asked here.**

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Function.prototype)
["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "constructor", "bind", "toString", "call", "apply"]

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object)
["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype", "keys", "create", "defineProperty", "defineProperties", "freeze", "getPrototypeOf", "getOwnPropertyDescriptor", "getOwnPropertyNames", "is", "isExtensible", "isFrozen", "isSealed", "preventExtensions", "seal"]
```

Comment: ECMA-262 3rd edition, sections *15.2.3*, *15.3.3* and *15.4.3* specify that all these constructors have a `length` property, whose value is 1.

Comment: Thanks for clarification :) but why 1 any specific reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array`, `Function`, and `Object` are all constructors, so they're all functions. The `length` property of a function specifies the number of (named) arguments that the function takes. From ECMA-262 3rd edition, section 15:

> Every built-in Function object described in this section—whether as a constructor, an
>   ordinary function, or both—has a length property whose value is an integer. Unless otherwise specified,
>   this value is equal to the largest number of named arguments shown in the section headings for the function description, including optional parameters.

And as DCoder pointed out:

> ECMA-262 3rd edition, sections 15.2.3, 15.3.3 and 15.4.3 specify that all these constructors have a length property, whose value is 1.

To your point about static fields: There is no such thing as static fields in JavaScript, as there are no classes in JavaScript. There are only primitive values, objects, and functions. Objects and functions (which behave as objects as well) have *properties*.

One thing that may be confusing is that `Function` is in fact a function. A little-known fact is that you can create functions using this constructor. For example:

```js
var identity = new Function("a", "b", "return a")
console.log(identity(42))
```

The above will print `42`. Now notice two things: `Function` actually takes arguments and does something with them; and I passed more than one argument to the `Function` constructor, even though `Function.length` is equal to `1`. The result, `identity`, is also a function, whose `length` property is set to the value `2`, since it's a function with two arguments.

Comment: I am interested in static length of Function class not the length property of individual instances or function objects. You are talking about Function.prototype not Function. Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Function.prototype) also returns length property that is different thing.

Comment: I assure you, we're talking about the same thing. `Function.length` is equal to `1` because `Function` is a function (that's the confusing part) that has a single named argument. Note that `Function` recognizes more than one argument, but only one happens to be named in the internal implementation.

Comment: Any property on constructor is shared by all function objects. Am i wrong?

Comment: That is incorrect. The code inside the constructor will assign objects their properties, and the `new` keyword will assign the `__proto__` property to `Constructor.prototype`, which will also be used for property lookup. The there is no relationship between the properties of a constructor and its instances.

Comment: f = new Function("x","y","return x+y;"); f.length is 2 but that is specific to variable f or this function. What about static thing that is defined on entire function class?

Comment: Ok, for a moment if i agree what about length of Object?

Comment: > typeof Object
"function"
> typeof Function
"function"
> typeof Array
"function"

They are all functions. Hence when @seliopou talks about the length property of functions, it applies to the Function, Object, and Array constructors as well.

Comment: *"there are no classes in JavaScript"* This seems outdated now.

Answer (score 0):

All the above mentioned are functions, which has a property length, saying tjhe number of arguments the function takes. Thats why they have length as static variable here.

```
fun = function( a) { alert(a); }
//fun.length = 1
```

Comment: this length property is inherited by Function.prototype not Function.