# Why do functions have a length property?

Tags: javascript

I've been fiddling with some code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f4Z6p/).  For some reason, a function was detected as an abstract array b.c. it has a length property on it.  Not a major issue, b.c. it is 0, but I found this bizarre.

```
var test_set = [null,
                undefined,
                NaN,
                true,
                false,
                1,
                'a',
                {test:'test'},
                [0], 
                function(){}, 
                /test/
               ];

var index, 
    key,
    test;

function isArrayAbstract (obj) {
    return (obj != null) && (obj.length === +obj.length);
};

for(index = 0; index < test_set.length; index++){
    test = isArrayAbstract(test_set[index]);
    console.log('Mark | ' + test_set[index]);
    console.log(test);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking *why* it exists or *what* it is? One of those two is easy to answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the length property of the Function, Array, and Object constructors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050709/what-is-the-length-property-of-the-function-array-and-object-constructors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

> length is a property of a function object, and indicates how many arguments the function expects, i.e. the number of formal parameters. **By contrast, arguments.length is local to a function and provides the number of arguments actually passed to the function.**

See the examples :

```
console.log( (function () {}).length );  /* 0 */
console.log( (function (a) {}).length ); /* 1 */
console.log( (function (a, b) {}).length ); /* 2 etc. */
console.log( (function (...args) {}).length ); /* 0, rest parameter is not counted */
```

Refer [ECMAScript Language Specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15) as well:

> Every built-in Function object described in this clause—whether as a constructor, an ordinary function, or both—has a length property whose value is an integer. Unless otherwise specified, this value is equal to the largest number of named arguments shown in the subclause headings for the function description, including optional parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The `length` property specifies the number of arguments expected by the function.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length):

> `length` is a property of a function object, and indicates how many arguments the function expects, i.e. the number of formal parameters.

```
(function(){}).length;  // 0
(function(a){}).length; // 1
```

Comment: @pure_code.mom: While functions have a `.length` property, they don't have numerical properties. It's not comparable with the `.length` property of arrays or array-like objects, it has a different meaning.

Comment: @pure_code.mom That's what the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object is for.

Answer (score 1):

A function's length property is the number of arguments it is defined to receive. Example

```
function foo(a,b){
...
}
```

In this case foo.length will be 2.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a purpose for the `length` field on a function. From the [MDN documentation for Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length):

> Specifies the number of arguments expected by the function.